# open failed EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: android, file-io, android-sdcard, file-access

i was trying to save some strings to sd card. but it was throwing this exception open failed EACCES (Permission denied). i tested this on a device(asus zenfone 5). i have declared the permissions in the manifest file-WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, my sd card is mounted and data can be written and read from it(i have personally checked it by copying some mp3 files and playing them). as this was a phone specific app and the phone has an internal and external storage in it and i want to save the file in external sdcard i wrote a code like this. i got the absolute path of external sd card using terminal emulator app by using "cd" and "ls" commands. My phone is not rooted so i cant issue any permission changes directly. I have tried all possible methods possible by google and stackoverflow. please help me out

```
public void savePublicExternalFile(String data){
        File folder = new File("/Removable/MicroSD/");
        //i have also tried File folder = new File("/Removable/MicroSD");
        File myFile = new File(folder,"mydata.txt");
        WriteData(myFile, data);



    }

    private void WriteData(File myFile, String data){

        if(t){
            Log.i("AbsolutePath",myFile.getAbsolutePath());
            t = false;
        }

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream=null;
        try {
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
            fileOutputStream.write(data.getBytes());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("exception",e.toString());
        }  finally {
            if(fileOutputStream!=null){
                try {
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.i("exception", e.toString());
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that your *Asus Zenfon*e is running on `Android` versions `>= KitKat`. So, since *KITKAT* due to major changes in SD card write policy, you won't be able to write on SD card except on your App Private folder ( which is `/storage/../data/com.example/` in *SD card*).

To access this folder on SD card, there is new `API` added in `KitKat`. This API will return an array of Files containing path of all app private folders.

```
File[] files = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(context, null)
```

By default, `0th` position path is similar to path returned by older API `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` and this is primary storage. `1st` position (in general) will be other storage directory which is SD card generally. Use this file path to write on SD card. Make sure to verify Mounted state of SD card before writing anything on it.

Hope this help. Let me know if you are facing any other issue.

Comment: this was helpful, i was able to write inside android folder of sd card, because files[1] gave me that path, is there any method by which i can get root path of sd card using this or any other method ?

Answer (score 1):

Few day ago I tried this code for saving an image and it works for me.

```
void saveFile() {
    String RootDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "any_folder";

    File myDir = new File(RootDir);
    myDir.mkdirs();

    String fname = "mydata.txt";
    File file = new File(myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists())
        file.delete();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        out.write(data.getBytes());
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Toast.makeText(AddText.this, "File saved to 'any_folder' folder",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain me whats the difference between your answer and BlackHamm3rJack's answer?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an hardcoded directory, try using a call to `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory` and open a file by appending the name to that path

Comment: Did that even but with no positive result

Comment: Yes i am still getting the same problem.

Comment: Please provide entire log of the exception

Comment: @RisingUp here is the log "I/exception﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Removable/MicroSD/mydata.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)"

Comment: Pass to `WriteData` the string of the file instead of the class, because the `File` class, afaik needs the file to exist

Comment: @BlackHamm3rJack can you please elaborate. i amn't able to understand.

Comment: if there is any confusion that "file not found" due to java.io.FileNotFoundException is that there is no file called "mydata.txt", so i have created one "mydata.txt" in external sdcard folder and tried again. still i get the same log i have posted above @RisingUp has asked

Comment: Can you check if the above code works on an emulator

Comment: @BlackHamm3rJack i didn't mean you are wrong i was just clarifying. you are helping me and i am grateful of you. don't feel bad

Comment: @RisingUp this time same error is reported. and this time i didn't use hard coded string path i used Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory but the log shows the same error as follows. this thing has been severely haunting me from last night. in btw the log is as follows " java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard/Download/mydata.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)"

Comment: This link should help you. It talks about calling openFileOutput() to get a FileOutputStream that writes to a file in your internal directory. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Comment: But he's trying to write to the sd card